# How to use Android Fragment in Flutter plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, android-fragments, dart

I need to wrap SDK created in native code iOS/Android into Flutter. On Android side there is some functionality where my Fragment or Activity needs to extend **SDK** Fragment or Activity to implement custom view.
My question is how I can wrap **SDK** Fragment or Activity in **Flutter plugin** and let extends this on flutter project side using my plugin ? I other words I would like to have a Widget which can extend Fragment or Activity using my plugin to have **ability to show Widget ui in SDK**.

Using FlutterFragment, FlutterActivity in plugin is right way ?

I mean:
Flutter project (Widget) <-> Flutter plugin (FlutterFragment or FlutterActivity attached to native SDK Fragment or Activity)

If not what is a possible solution ?

Comment: If you think @pddthinh's answer helped you please accept it

Comment: hi, @piczaj can you help me, please if you got a way to do this?

Comment: check this answer, It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133974/15043368

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and here is my solution:

- Implement a FlutterPlugin that supports `ActivityAware`, refer to this [FlutterPlugin with ActivityAware](https://medium.com/flutter/modern-flutter-plugin-development-4c3ee015cf5a) on how to cache the Activity, as well as `MethodCallHandler` (to communicate with the FlutterWidget app).
- Implement a MethodCall e.g. ***SHOW_NATIVE_FRAGMENT*** in which it will attach the native fragment. Note: need to dynamically add a View as a container for the fragment

  ```
       int id = 0x123456;
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams vParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
       );
       FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);
       container.setLayoutParams(vParams);
       container.setId(id);
       activity.addContentView(container, vParams);
  ```
- Then attach the Fragment to the Activity

```
        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(id, nativeFragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

- When you are done with the Fragment, remember to call the `MethodChannel.Result` with either `success()` or `error()` otherwise, the FlutterWidget will be blocked forever.
- On the FlutterWidget side, call the MethodChannel with

```
        static Future<void> showNativeFragment() async {
            await _channel.invokeMethod("SHOW_NATIVE_FRAGMENT");
        }
```

And also make sure that your FlutterWidget's application Activity extends `FlutterFragmentActivity`.

Comment: when casting to a FragmentActivity i am getting an error `MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @DerekHannah, perhaps you are getting that error because your `MainActivity`'s based class is something else, not a `FragmentActivity`. In my case, the `MainActivity` is a subclass of the `FlutterFragmentActivity`.

Comment: I have quite a same problem,  I am using Flutter Platform View, inside that I want to show a fragment. The problem is, If I use `activity.addContentView(container, vParams)` it become the main layout of whole app and i cant see Flutter UI. If I don't do addContentView then it doesn't trigger some of the lifecycles of fragment and fragment UI is not properly working