# How to add native Android layout XML code to a Flutter Application?

Tags: android, flutter

i have this code from a documentation that's for android but i want it for my flutter app so how can i add this layout to my flutter app:

```
<com.lawrencespring.payment.widget.FIBButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonBuy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

i tried many ways but was unable to achieve it

Comment: You will need different solutions for Android and iOS. Start with exploring how to embed fragments, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746709/how-to-use-android-fragment-in-flutter-plugin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.